# Is this DB scehema correct for a Dating site?

Tags: mysql, asp.net, database-schema, social-networking

I am going to build dating app like match.com , PlentyOfFish.com.

I am going to build it from the scratch. I am using asp.net and MYSQL as my DB.

So lets play the scenario from the begin. Shall we?

A man wants to find a woman.
So man register in my site.
Then site will ask questions from him about his preferences.
eg: Your hair color,
ethnicity,
education level,
Salary etc...

In the mean time site will ask about the partner who wants be with him.
Her hair color,
ethnicity etc... and so on...

So here is my database structure.I know this pretty complex. 
But lets build it from step by step.First I just want to register this man, Take his preferences and his partner's preferences. So then app should do the matching. that's enough for now. ( Later have to build sending friend request, chat app and so on)

SO here is the DB schema I came up with.

I need to register this user.
This is the user table

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `user_id_pk` int(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email`
  `salt,
  `password,
  `password_modified_date,
  `recovery_email,
  `is_verified`
//--More fields
)
```

Then the Question table

```
CREATE TABLE `question` (
  `question_id_pk`,
  `question`,
  `is_active`,
  PRIMARY KEY (`question_id_pk`)
)
```

This table contains the all questions

This is the answer table. This contains all the answers for above question table

```
CREATE TABLE `answer` (
  `answer_id_pk`,
  `question_id_fk,
  `answer`,
  PRIMARY KEY (`answer_id_pk`)
)
```

So Now I need to map this question and answers with the user and the partner

So this is the seeking persons table

```
CREATE TABLE `me` (
  `me_id_pk` AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id_fk`,
  `answer_id_fk`,
  `question_id_fk,
  PRIMARY KEY (`me_id_pk`)
)
```

This is the partner's preferences

```
CREATE TABLE `partner` (
  `partner_id_pk AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id_fk`,
  `answer_id_fk`,
  `question_id_fk`,
  PRIMARY KEY (`partner_id_pk`)
)
```

So matching happen between this me table and the partner table.
If we take specific person's me table then the app will looking for other me tables which is matching with that specific person's partner table's requirements.
If those matches they are matching.

So far I came up with this schema. AM I doing this right? I need to consider scalability and performance. I know there is no right way to do this. At least you can improve my solution.

Comment: _"I need to consider scalability and performance"_ - then starting out with a relational database might not be the way to go, because your database is going to become your monolithic bottleneck which will become very expensive to scale. Anyway this is off-topic, too broad and opinion-based.

Comment: @CodeCaster I am not asking for a opinion. I presented what I did. So I am asking am I doing right. :) Thanks for the comment

Comment: There is no singular, correct way to model this, so yeah it's opinion-based.